# Why is UPDATE creating a new record?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, submit, record

For event listing page. After inserting record into db I capture last ID with

```
//Store ID[LAST]
    $ID = mysqli_insert_id($db);
```

Next the page shows event formatted for easy reading.
Then user can hold or approve item for publication with 2 buttons: Draft, Publish. I use submits buttons for each:

```
//Check ID value (use for testing)
    echo "<p>ID = ".$ID."</p>\n";

    echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='GET'>
    <input type='submit' name='submitDraft' value='Draft' />
    <input type='submit' name='submitPublish' value='Publish' />
    </form>";
```

Now I use conditional to update record according to button chosen. (Note `connect.php` is include that manages passcodes and connection statement.)

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["submitDraft"])) {
    include('includes/connect.php');
    $sql="UPDATE sessions SET postit='0' WHERE ID='$ID'";
    if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
        }

        mysqli_close($db);
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST["submitPublish"])) {
    include('includes/connect.php');
    $sql="UPDATE sessions SET postit='1' WHERE ID='$ID'";
    if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
        }

        mysqli_close($db);
    }
```

My problem is UPDATE statement adds new record to table but should update same record. What is my mistake please.

Comment: Do you require ID to be unique for each record in the table?

Comment: do you have a trigger defined on that table?

Comment: @Jay Patel yes - ID must be unique.

Comment: @Rahul Why is trigger example?

Comment: @parboy you don't have insert query anywhere on this PHP page right?

Comment: Yes - good comment. See solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this. Because form resubmit whole page, insert statement is run each time and add new record. This record also get update so appear like UPDATE is add new record. Really INSERT make new record and UPDATE change 'postit' field in same time. To fix I add conditional if `$_REQUEST not equal submitDraft or submitPublish then INSERT`, else it skip over INSERT. Also I just see same kind of answer from @Jay Patel and @SBA. Thank you to both

Answer (score 1):

I think you should hold the last insert id in a session value and use it when the user click Draft or Publish since it appears the insertion of data and events draft or publish happen at different times.

```
//Store ID[LAST]
$_SESSION['ID'] = mysqli_insert_id($db);

 if(isset($_SESSION['ID'])){
   $ID=$_SESSION['ID'];
   //Check ID value (use for testing)
   echo "<p>ID = ".$ID."</p>\n";
  }


echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='GET'>
<input type='submit' name='submitDraft' value='Draft' />
<input type='submit' name='submitPublish' value='Publish' />
</form>";

if (isset($_REQUEST["submitDraft"])) {
include('includes/connect.php');
 if(isset($_SESSION['ID'])){
   $ID=$_SESSION['ID'];
  }
$sql="UPDATE sessions SET postit='0' WHERE ID='$ID'";
if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
    }

    mysqli_close($db);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST["submitPublish"])) {
include('includes/connect.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['ID'])){
   $ID=$_SESSION['ID'];
  }
$sql="UPDATE sessions SET postit='1' WHERE ID='$ID'";
if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
    }

    mysqli_close($db);
}
```

Comment: Setting SESSION variable still adds new record. Check ID value test increments ++ each time Draft or Publish is click.

Comment: @parboy  try including connection once at the top of the page so no new connection is established when publish or draft button is clicked. update shouldn't lead to data insertion so u put connection at the top and lets see